Text above radio buttons, how can I make it wrap?
I'm currently making a questionnaire and have it so that the questionnaire is placed horizontally and with 4 radio buttons. The current code looks like this:
package com.example.jetquestionnaire.ui.theme

import android.widget.RadioButton
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Row
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.height
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.foundation.selection.selectable
import androidx.compose.material3.RadioButton
import androidx.compose.material3.RadioButtonDefaults
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextAlign
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp

@Composable
fun RadioButtonTest() {
    val options = listOf("3", "2", "1", "0")
    var selectedOption by remember { mutableStateOf(options[0]) }
    val textAboveRadioButtons = listOf(
        "High",
        "Medium-High",
        "Medium-Low",
        "Low",
    )
    //custom colour
    val customSelectedColor = Color(0xFF5799FC)
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(16.dp),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly,
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
    ) {
        options.zip(textAboveRadioButtons).forEach { (option, textAbove) ->
            Column(
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .selectable(
                        selected = (selectedOption == option),
                        onClick = { selectedOption = option }
                    )
                    .padding(8.dp),
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = textAbove,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(bottom = 5.dp),

                )
                RadioButton(
                    selected = (selectedOption == option),
                    onClick = { selectedOption = option },
                    colors = RadioButtonDefaults.colors(
                        selectedColor = customSelectedColor,
                        unselectedColor = Color.Gray
                    ),
                )
                Text(
                    text = option,
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 5.dp),
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

Now the thing is, the text above the buttons are in a "listOf" list and I want to put  longer text in the textAboveButtons. But when I put longer text, it pushes the other buttons and text to the right and spills out of the screen. I want to make it wrap and go down. How do I approach this?
With short Text:

With long Text:


Did you try to use a Modifier like width or height to resize your composables?

The Text composables will already wrap their content when not enough space. The problem is that this doesn't apply for the first Texts, because when they are layed out, they still have the entire row available.
What you need is that each Text composable takes the other Texts into account when determining its width. You can do that by applying the weight modifier. That will allow all siblings with the same weight to take up the same width. Since you wrapped each Text in a Column, you must apply the weight modifier to the Column, because only the Columns are sibling to one another.
What weight you actually specify is not important, just make sure it is the same for all Columns. Since they are generated in a for loop that is easy:
Column(
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
    modifier = Modifier
        .selectable(
            selected = (selectedOption == option),
            onClick = { selectedOption = option }
        )
        .padding(8.dp)
        .weight(1f),
) {
    // ...
}


Okay thank you, I will try to apply this

update: After adding weight, the text does wrap and go below. How do I make it align in the center though?

Apply the modifier fillMaxHeight() to the Column and set the verticalArrangement parameter to Arrangement.Bottom. If you need more help to find an appropriate layout you should ask another question.
